# Can´t manage to Load HTML content into DIV using .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to build a very simple APP, base on HTML and JavaScript, that simply loads html pages and presents them.

Each Content is supposed to be loaded inside a DIV (#MainContent).
I found many post saying I should use $(#MainContent).load('file.html'), but for some reason nothing happens wen I click the button.

Here is my JS code:

```
$(document).bind( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {
    if ( typeof data.toPage === "string" ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#MainContent').load(data.toPage);
    }
});
```

Notes:

a) I know the script is runing since If I put an Alert(), it fires up each time I click.

b) If I use: Alert(data.toPage); I get the full path of "file.html" (the file I want to load), so all good here, I think;

c) I'm using 'jquery-1.9.1.min.js', and 'jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js'... does the problem resides here?

Comment: Define "full patch". It looks like a typo. But I can't tell if you mean "path" or "page" and if the latter if you actually mean "html source".

Comment: Why are you checking if typeof data.toPage === "string"? It seems like this is pointless, also can cause issues. and e.preventDefault(); should be first line to run.

and IF data.toPage is infact a string, why would you use .load() instead of .html()?

Comment: Have you checked `#MainContent` exists on the page :)

Comment: does .load trigger pagebeforechange? maybe you should bind the event to a container rather to the whole document?

Comment: @Quentin: Yes it was a Typo, It is corrected now. What I mean whit "full path", is something like: "file:///c:/mydir/myapp/file.html".

Comment: @Slugge: If I do not put this "if", for some reason I can not use e.preventDefault(), the first page simply wont load.

Comment: @rtpHarry: Yes #MainContent does exist, in fact, if I use $('#MainContent').htlm(data.toPage), the content of #MainContent changes, but it hit only prints the file path: file:///c:/mydir/myapp/file.html

Comment: @Alex: Just tried your solution, but now I get an error saying "Error Loading Page"

Comment: What does your browser's JavaScript console say? I'm guessing it is complaining about a lack of access control origin header and not being allowed to make requests from null. That's an error message you should Google if you are getting it.

Comment: @Quentin: Thanks, you put me on the right track... and guess what? It was working all along. The problem was not with my code but with Chrome. For some reason it does not run that peace of code. FireFox runs it with flying colors, and I just tried it on my Android runs like a charm. But now my question is: will this work on other platforms? IOS for exemple?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#MainContent').html(data.toPage);
```

Comment: I tried that already, ir does Load something... but the string "file.hmtl" is loaded, and not it's content.